# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' fastapi docker

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app 

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --requirement /requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0" , "--reload" , "--port", "8000"]
```

when i used

> **docker-compose up -d**
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

- the folders in Fastapi framework:
- fastapi

  - app

    -main.py
- ```
     language_detector.py
  ```
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose

Comment: you need an `__index__.py` in your app folder i think ...

Comment: Can you show your docker-compose file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0" , "--reload" , "--port", "8000"]
```

Your work directory is /app and the main.py file is already there. So you don't need to call app.main module. Just call main.py script directly in CMD.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the /app folder before

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app 

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --requirement /requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0" , "--reload" , "--port", "8000"]
```

And launching it:

docker-compose up --build

Comment: the same error .

Answer (score 1):

The issue could likely be caused by how you define the volume mounts on docker compose:
More on mounts [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)